# In a Django template, is it possible to send the whole variable document to a template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tagging

If I render a template using this document:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }
```

In Django templates, I can render html using the value of "a" like this:

```
{{ a }}
```

But is it possible to send the whole document to a template tag?  ie, all this?

```
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }
```

So that my tag can access arbitrary elements?

Comment: The proper terminology for what you call "document" is "context" in Django. And can you clarify? Are you writing a custom template tag and want to access the entire context there? Or you are using some builtin template tag?

Comment: Hi Abdul, yes the entire document is placed there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your dict as string or you can use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) to this for you.

**Example 1**

```
def index(request):
    my_dict = '{"a":1, "b":2}'
    return render(request, "index.html", {'data':my_dict})
```

**Example 2**

```
import json

def index(request):
    my_dict = json.dumps({"a":1, "b":2})
    return render(request, "index.html", {'data':my_dict})
```

and inside your template just do like this

```
{{data}} <!--- this will output actual dictionary eg. { "a": 1, "b": 2 } --->
```

Answer (score 0):

In django framework we send data from view.py to template using context dictionary. The general format for this is:

1. using function based views.

   def index(request):

   ```
   return render(request, 'index.html',{'injectme':'this is context',
   'inject_me':'this is next context'})
   ```

now in template you can access this as:

```
{{injectme}}    
{{inject_me}}
```

2. using class based views

   class abc(TemplateView):

   ```
   def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
       context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['inject_me']='basic injection'
       context['injectme']='second injection'
       return context
   ```

now in the template:

```
{{inject_me}}
{{injectme}}
```

hope your confusion cleared out.

Comment: Thanks Ran, this was not my question though.  I wanted to be able to send the whole document to a tag, so I was able to add an extra tag in the context by adding an additional "context" node with a deepcopy of the document for convenience.